# How can I make REST calls to a AWS API Gateway from a lambda?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda

I'm having a hard time finding guidance on the best way to call an AWS Api Gateway from a .Net lambda. I have seen some posts using the .Net HttpClient, signing the authorization headers, etc. BUT....I find it hard to believe this is the recommended way if the lambda is within the same VPC. Isn't there a better way than all the manual HTTP header building, signing, etc? I thought the AWS SDK might prove fruitful, but it seems that's just for managing AWS resources, not consuming Api Gateway endpoints. Isnt there an Amazon library that allows this type of consumption that shields us from all the authorization signing, etc.?

My scenario: I have an Api Gateway that I need to consume to do a simple value lookup on an internal business API. I have a lambda that responds to SNS events, performs the lookup, then acts upon the data and moving it to an RDS elsewhere.

UPDATE: Looking into step functions, as @Gaz_Edge suggested. Would this be a good fit for this orchestration?

Comment: Normally, Lambda does not call another Lambda function directly or thru API Gateway as you are then paying for a Lambda function to wait for another one. Given that your Lambda function can directly `invoke` another Lambda function with an API call.